# Adding space to more symbols

Tags: preg-replace

i have this string for example

```
$string="put@returns-between|par/agra\phs";  // @-|/\
```

how to add space to each sympol with one command
this is result
$result :"put @ returns - between | par / agra \ phs
i have used this solution but I would like to know if there is better than this

```
<?php
$string="put@returns-between|par/agra\phs";  // @-|/\
 $str=preg_replace("/[@]/", " @ ", $string);
  $str=preg_replace("/[-]/", " - ", $str);
  $str=preg_replace("/[|]/", " | ", $str);
  $str=preg_replace("/[\/]/", " / ", $str);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$string="put@returns-between|par/agra\phs";  // @-|/\
$str=preg_replace("/([@|\-|\||\\\\|\/])/", " $1 ", $string);
echo $str;
```

see the [demo](https://eval.in/670877), hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
$string = "put@returns-between|par/agra\phs";
$str = preg_replace("~([-@|\\\\/])~", " $1 ", $string);
echo $str;
```

**Output:**

```
put @ returns - between | par / agra \ phs
```